# How pull Artifact Registry images from a on-premise k8s cluster?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, kubernetes, docker-registry

I know I should create a service account key, with JSON credentials, from Google Cloud Console and give the appropriate role.

Then I should use the kubectl command to create the secret:

```
kubectl -n=NAMESPACE_NAME create secret docker-registry SECRET_NAME --docker-server HOST_NAME 
--docker-username _json_key --docker-email ANY_VALID_EMAIL --docker-password="$(cat ~/key.json)"
```

but in all examples, I found is referred:

```
--docker-server 'gcr.io'
```

while I should use the new Artifact Registry.

The problem is that is not clear to me which one is the right path for the HOST_NAME:

- LOCATION-docker.pkg.dev
- https://LOCATION-docker.pkg.dev
- LOCATION-docker.pkg.dev/PROJECT_NAME
- ...
- (other alternatives)

I tried several times but each time the deployment was not able to download the image.
(I added the secret with the credential to the SA and I am sure that is mounted and used from the deployment to try to download the images).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the right configuration.

As described [there](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/docker/names) I should use:

```
LOCATION-docker.pkg.dev/PROJECT-ID/REPOSITORY
```

as HOST_NAME on the secret creation.